# Ignore specific requirement in composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm currently using composer for managing my projects requirements. One of the packages I use have a bug, which is fixed in the dev branch of this package, so I used `"dev-dev@dev"`.

The problem is, the composer.json file of the given package, also requires and dev package of another package, which I dont want to install (actually I can't because of other requirements..)

Is there a way to tell composer, to ignore the requirements of my dev package, or how could I sovle this without patching the extension on my own?

Answer (score -1):

need a --ignore-platform-requirements or such flag that skips those requirements while loading packages

Comment: that flag only ignores `php`, `hhvm`, `lib-*` and `ext-*` requirements